# test for data type errors in loops java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, sentinel

Yes, this is a homework problem. I am a beginner in programming. I am good at using if/else with for loops, since my professor asked us to while loop. I am confused.This is the question...

Q1) Suppose you are writing a game-playing program that involves 2-digit numbers, each number being composed of 2 different digits. Test if whether numbers entered in a sequence are accepted to be used in this game. Test for errors in input (including type).

My while loop to check the data type works fine at first, but after an int has been entered and I can't check the data type. Can anyone explain the problem to me please? Thank you...

```
public static void main(String[] args){

int num = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a 2-digit number. The digits should be different. zero to stop");

while(!input.hasNextInt()){
  System.out.println("Not an integer,try again " + num);
  input.next();
 }
num = input.nextInt();


while(num != 0){

while(num < 10 || num >= 99){
 System.out.println("NOT good for your game! " + num );
 System.out.println("Enter a 2-digit number. The digits should be different. Zero to stop");
  num = input.nextInt();
    }

 System.out.println("Good for your game! Play! " + num);
   num = input.nextInt();
    }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Which part has you confused exactly?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  The data type is int.  What do you mean check the data type?  Also, what does that have anything to do with a while loop?

Comment: The first issue I see is that you are checking for numbers less then ten and greater then 99, which would make them 3 digits, this is correct but it doesn't test for numbers such as 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, and 99, which you don't want since they are the same digit

Comment: Even a bigger hint: 

`if (your_variable % 11 = 0)
{
   system.out.println("Hey, you have a number with the same digits, like 11 , 22 , 33 ,44 ,55 ,66 ,77 ,88 ,99");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop in the first checked the System.in is entering a digit (int) or not: `while(!input.hasNextInt())`, but when you first input a digit, the loop exit and it enter into the next 2 loops:

```
while(num != 0){
    while(num < 10 || num >= 99){
```

and then in the end of the inner loop you have:

```
num = input.nextInt();
```

This means you already assume the next input would be an int. So if you enter a non-digit input, program will throw an exception.

I would suggest you to change the whole loop into:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num = 1;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a 2-digit number. The digits should be different. zero to stop");
        if (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Not an integer,try again " + num);
        } else {
            num = input.nextInt();
            if (num < 10 || num >= 99) {
                System.out.println("NOT good for your game! " + num);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Good for your game! Play! " + num);
            }
        }
    } while(num != 0);

    input.close();
    System.out.println("game stop");
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I think i get it now. I have a question, so I can't use while loop to approach this problem?

Comment: I think you can, I just put it at the last of a `do ... while` loop. you can also move your condition to the begining as a `while {} ` loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Number1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String prompt = "Enter a 2-digit number. The digits should be different. Zero to stop:";

    getInt(sc,prompt);

}


public static void getInt(Scanner sc,String prompt) {

    System.out.println(prompt);
    int num;

    while (!sc.hasNextInt())
    {
        System.out.println("Not an integer, Try again");
        sc.next();
    }

    num = sc.nextInt();

    while(num != 0) {
        if (num < 10 || num >= 99 || num == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Not good for your game!");
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Good for your game! Play!");
        }

        System.out.println(prompt);
        num = sc.nextInt();

    }

 }
```

}